# TDengine database data migration tool

Tags: tdengine

I am trying to migration all the data of my TDengine database to another server with better specs. Normally, I can write some scripts to do it, but it could take me a lot of time. I am wondering if there is any tool for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try taosdump,
here is the doc:
[taosdump usage](https://www.taosdata.com/blog/2020/03/09/1334.html)